# Is there a Goto function in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a function in Dart which acts as an equivalent to the Goto function, wherein I could transfer the programs control to a specified label.

For example:

```
var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
if (prefs.getString("TimetableCache") == null || refreshing) {
    var response = await http.get(
    Uri.encodeFull("A website",);
    data = JsonDecoder().convert(response.body);
    try {
        if (response != null) {
            prefs.setString("TimetableCache", response.body);
        }
    } catch (Exception) {
        debugPrint(Exception);
    }
   } else {
data = prefs.getString("TimetableCache");
}

if (data != null) {
    try {
       //Cool stuff happens here
    } catch (Exception) {
    prefs.setString("TimetableCache", null);
    }
}
```

I have an http request and before I want to move on with my 'cool stuff' I have a try catch which sees if anything is in the `TimetableCache` location of the `SharedPreferences` of the machine. When it catches the exception I would ideal have a goto method to send it back to the top line again to retry getting the data.

In c# you can use `goto refresh;`, for example, and the code will then start executing wherever the identifier `refresh:` is.

Is there a dart version of this?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a Goto in general. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, Dart supports labels. With `continue` and `break` you can jump to labels.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_loops.htm

> ```
> void main() { 
>    outerloop: // This is the label name 
>    
>    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
>       print("Innerloop: ${i}"); 
>       innerloop: 
>       
>       for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) { 
>          // Quit the innermost loop 
>          if (j > 3 ) break ; 
>          
>          // Do the same thing 
>          if (i == 2) break innerloop; 
>          
>          // Quit the outer loop 
>          if (i == 4) break outerloop; 
>          
>          print("Innerloop: ${j}"); 
>       } 
>    } 
> }
>
> void main() { 
>    outerloop: // This is the label name 
>    
>    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
>       print("Outerloop:${i}"); 
>       
>       for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) { 
>          if (j == 3){ 
>             continue outerloop; 
>          } 
>          print("Innerloop:${j}"); 
>       } 
>    } 
> }
> ```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30011

> ```
> switch (x) {
>   case 0:
>     ...
>     continue foo; // s_c
>   foo:
>   case 1: // s_E (does not enclose s_c)
>     ...
>     break;
> }
> ```

See also

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12641818/217408
- [Labels - break vs continue vs goto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46792159/labels-break-vs-continue-vs-goto)